# Use datetime as column alias in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

Hopefully this is a quick one for someone! I've been searching for a while with no real answers to the question. I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2000. I have a variable `@DayToCheck` which is a datetime.

```
@DayToCheck datetime
```

I need to use that for a column I am counting on. It's not however working. I have tried converting to a varchar, but it doesn't like that either. Here's the two count columns I need to use.

```
sum(case when startdate=@DayToCheck then 1 else 0 end) as CONVERT(varchar, @DayToCheck, 103),
sum(case when startdate=DATEADD(day,-7,@DayToCheck) then 1 else 0 end) as DATEADD(day,-7,@DayToCheck)
```

So the above should have two columns and their alias should be the date (for column one) and -7 days off the date for column two.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You have to do this in dynamic sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use dynamic sql. So maybe something like this:

```
DECLARE @DayToCheck datetime
SET @DayToCheck=GETDATE()

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @query=
N'SELECT
    sum(case when startdate=@DayToCheck then 1 else 0 end) as '+
    CONVERT(varchar, @DayToCheck, 103)+',
    sum(case when startdate=DATEADD(day,-7,@DayToCheck) then 1 else 0 end) as '+
    CONVERT(varchar, @DayToCheck, 103)+'
FROM
    table1'

EXECUTE(@query)
```